# Why Visual Studio contains two git.exe files

Tags: git, visual-studio

I'm configuring build machines to work with git repository. I found out that Visual Studio (2017, 2019) has already git.exe but in two locations:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Git\cmd (42 KB)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Git\mingw32\bin (2397 KB)
```

1. Why Visual Studio has two git.exe?
2. Why they have such big difference in size?
3. Should I use one of them with CI system? If yes then which?
4. Should I install git separately by installer from [Git page](https://git-scm.com/download/win)?

Answer (score 0):

4. Yes. [Git for Windows](https://gitforwindows.org/) will offer you the right download.

And learn to use git from the command line, while VS's helpers can make a few things easy you'll find far more answers for more complex things if you use git's own terminology and make use of the command line.

1. Installing Git for Windows also installs a similar pair of `git.exe` with the same relative locations. I suspect one forwards to the other. ("Why?" is a question for the developers of the Windows port.)
2. See above.
3. Use the one in the path... which the Git for Windows will set up for you (it is why, the first time you install it, you need to logoff and login).

Comment: https://github.com/git-for-windows/build-extra/blob/2a692f56003b149c84da5da18f8e8c2bbb452811/msi/GitUI_en-us.wxl#L18